# How do I exclude first two capital letters of a word using regex on Google spreadsheet?

Tags: regex

I have few words in a column on Google spreadsheet.

E.g. TTTyyy, AAAbbb, JJJkkk etc

I want to extract the word by excluding the first two capital letters.

Desired output is

Tyyy from TTTyyy, Abbb from AAAbbb, Jkkk from JJJkkk etc

Comment: Please post code snippets of what you have tried.

Comment: Are the first two letters always capital letters or do you have to check for that?

Comment: Mocha - I've not tried anything. New to regex.

Comment: ArSen - Good question. I have few of them without first two capital letters, it is either three capital letters or one capital letter. In case of one capital letter the output should be the same word.     E.g  For Tyyy output should be same word, Tyyy

Answer (score 0):

Googlesheets uses REGEXETRACT: [Google finds REGEXETRACT regex syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Cell C2 
 {="TTTyyy"}:

A cell like B2
 {=REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+")}

You can look up the regex in the reference:[A-Z] captures caps and {1} limits the caps to one; then [a-z] captures lowercase letters "+" one or more.

Comment: hdunn - Thank you. Got the desired output.